# Python bar chart border overlapping horizontal bars values

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, border

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPoSM.jpg)
the values of bars overlapping the borders. How to change the border so that bars with values should fit in properly

Comment: solved the problem by adding lines  ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

Answer (score 0):

```
#adding following lines solved the problem
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```